# Sorting the nearest place using firebase (android)

Tags: android, firebase, location

i have a project to sort data by the nearest location. I want to show list of vehicle based on the nearest location of user. I store latitude and longitude in firebase. Is there a way to implement it in my project? I have no idea and i haven't found clue about this.
this is my firebase :
[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJag3.png)

and this is my mockup to sorting the nearest vehicle :
[mockup nearest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaLkR.png)

Please help.. 
Thankyou.

Comment: Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask.

Comment: As B001 commented, please improve your question. and break your problem down in small problems, cause if you have a lat-lon database it's easy:
look in the firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) how to sort & filter data. filter example: startAt(yourLat-10); endAt(yourLat+10); to retreive every db entry with a Lat that is "close" to you.

Comment: sorry.. now, i've edited my question. please check it..

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). Using [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) distance projected on the x axis is longitude1-longitude2 and distance projected on the y axis latitude1-latitude2. I call this a flat earth theory and it should be accurate enough but for more precision [‘haversine’ formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) is more accurate but slower to calculate.

Comment: yes, thankyou for your answer.. but i have not clue how to implement it on my project.. @Pomagranite

Comment: I don't see your code so I have no way to help. Can you post the portion of code this question is about?